# OpenGl Implicit Circle function-- incomplete circle

Tags: opengl

I am having a little issue drawing a circle.  The function draws an almost complete circle and I am just missing a tiny bit of the loop.  I am assuming that the issue has something to do with an automatic redraw of something?

Here is the function

```
for(x = radius; x >= -radius; x -= 0.05)     // draw the plot
{   
    double temp = (radius * radius) - (x * x);
    y = sqrt(temp);
    glVertex2f(x, y);
}
for(x = -radius; x <= radius; x += 0.05)     // draw the plot
{   
    double temp = (radius * radius) - (x * x);
    y = sqrt(temp);
    glVertex2f(x, -y);
}
```

Would any of the other code be helpful?

Comment: Also, is this in a `glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP)`?

Comment: Sorry I just read your link..pure ignorance...I will absolutely start paying attention...this is in a glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP)

Comment: A link to an image might be helpful.

Comment: Make it `GL_LINE_LOOP` to connect the last and the first vertex. See if that solves your problem.

Comment: Do you *just* need to draw a circle, or do you *have* to use the implicit equation to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're experiencing is just a floating point precision issue. You assume your x values to go to exactly `-radius` (or `radius` repsectively) at the end of each loop, which it probably doesn't due to accumulated rounding errors from all the additions.

This is no problem at `-radius` since its merged with the start of the second loop anyway, but at the end it won't end at `radius`. Try to make the whole thing a `GL_LINE_LOOP` instead of a `GL_LINE_STRIP` to merge the first and last vertices into a line.

Comment: I sat and worked on this with my mentor today...we found that decreasing the amount that x was incremented or decremented mattered...the smaller the number the closer we got to the x axis.  But we never got it to close.  I tried the LINE_LOOP but since I am drawing the circle by halves, it ends up looping back to the beginning so I end up with a pacman that has a tiny mouth.  I'll update if I can figure it out!

Comment: @calvarado No, you shouldn't get a pacman, but a circle. At least if both of the loops in your code are in a single `glBegin/glEnd` and not two separate ones, because first you run from 0 to 180 and then from 180 back to 0, so it should work with a single `GL_LINE_LOOP`. In fact the gap getting smaller when decreasing the amount added to `x` exactly matches my expkanations of rounding errors, since this amount marks the maximum possible amount by which the last `x` value may "miss" `radius`. I wonder though, what mentor is not aware of the usual floating point issues.